# Global Vairable wont change values

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 2 javascript files in my HTML Page

```
<script src="File1.js">
</script>

<script src="File2.js">
</script>
```

In the first file I have a global variable.

```
var X="-1";
```

and this function

```
function LoadUser()
{
    X="1";

}
```

Now, in the second file I have this function

```
function WhoIsLog()
{
  alert(X);
}
```

The problem is, that X wont change its value even if the cookie results brings the expected value. I need X new value in the second file. The alert results always is "-1".

I have also confirmed that the LoadUser() is the first function to run.

Comment: Are you calling `LoadUser()` before `WhoIsLog()`?

Comment: yes. First the page loads and run the function LoadUser(). Then I click a button to run the function WhoIsLog() and the alert persist as "-1".

Comment: I think you should post the entire code of both files.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/wXGkKW3oxFn4NfsnX4tl?p=preview

Comment: @KevinB - the first function should be in the first file (and I'm not sure in which files the calls to each function are made.. OP, help us out there?)

Comment: fixed, same link, still can't recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure it's global assign it to the window obj.

```
window.x = -1;
```

Or post the entire code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: You might want to use an uppercase `X` there

Comment: Agreed, but imo use lowercase unless it's needed as it could lead to confusion...

Comment: Absolutely agreed, and imo don't use generic (one letter) names as it may conflict with common properties

Comment: Weeeeee agrees all around!

Comment: This works. IDK what window means, but it really worked.

Comment: Window is thee global object...